# How to solve simultaneous equations with modulo arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have a system of two simultaneous equations:

$$a + 2b  = x \pmod 3$$
$$a + b = n$$

where $a, b \geq 0$  are integers.  The integer $x > 0$  is known modulo $3$ and the variable $n$ is an integer which is known. Both $a$ and $b$ are unknown.

> Is it possible to compute $b \pmod 2$ from these two equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second equation, $a=n-b$, so
$$
b\equiv x-n\pmod{3}
$$
There will be both even and odd solutions. If $x-n$ is odd, then
$b_1=x-n+3$ and $b_2=x-n+6$ will be solutions. Similarly if $x-n$ is even.

Comment: If there are both even and odd solutions for $b$, does this mean it is not possible?  $b \pmod 2$ is either $1$ or $0$ of course. Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @felipa Exactly so: in general you cannot draw information about $b\bmod 2$ just by knowing $b\bmod 3$.